# Centering a webpage - what am I missing?

Tags: css

I don't know what I'm missing. I am simply trying to center the page and nothing I do is working. I have the wrapper with "align-items: center;"... wouldn't that do it? Please help me out. Here is the current code:

```css
#Table_01 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 850px;
}
#wrapper {
  align-items: center;
}
#themeBG {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 849px;
  height: 333px;
}
#inThisIssue {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 333px;
  width: 266px;
  height: 65px;
}
#headlineNewDept {
  position: absolute;
  left: 266px;
  top: 333px;
  width: 584px;
  height: 65px;
}
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 398px;
  width: 266px;
  height: 2148px;
}
#main {
  position: absolute;
  left: 266px;
  top: 398px;
  width: 583px;
  height: 2149px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div align="center" id="wrapper">

  <div id="Table_01">
    <div id="themeBG">
      <img src="images/themeBG.jpg" width="849" height="333" alt="march image">
    </div>
    <div id="inThisIssue">
      <img src="images/inThisIssue.jpg" width="266" height="65" alt="in this issue...">
    </div>
    <div id="headlineNewDept">
      <img src="images/headlineNewDept.png" width="584" height="65" alt="headline - Our New Dept News">
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <img src="images/sidebar.jpg" width="266" height="2148" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="main">Main content.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using `flex` container? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: Why are you absolute positioning everything?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

Comment: `align-items` applies to flex containers. You should use `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex`.

Comment: Since you have everything absolute positioned, it will adhere to that. If you don't need absolute positioning, margin: auto will center a container div, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Table_01 {
margin:0 auto;
width:850px;
position:relative;
}
```

Position absolute with left 0 will slam it to the left.  Try the above.